# select specific ng-repeat items to highlight them somewhere else

Tags: angularjs

I have a list parsed by an ng-repeat directive. This list can be filtered by the user. This part is working fine.

The first item of the filtered list is highlighted somewhere else in the page.

I'm having some issue with the following:

When the user clicks on an item of the list, the highlighted item should be replaced by the clicked item until another filtering is done.

JSFiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/takuan/6c5x99by/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        id: 'a 1'
    }, {
        id: 'a 2'
    }, {
        id: 'b 3'
    }];
    $scope.itemFocus = function (item) {
        //we don't want to create a duplicate in a repeater
        //$scope.filteredItems[0] = item;
    };
}

<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchItems" />
    <p ng-if="filteredItems[0]">{{filteredItems[0].id}}</p>
</div>
<!-- some code -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (list | filter:searchItems)" 
        ng-click="itemFocus(item)">{{item.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why doesn't this one do the trick? http://jsfiddle.net/6c5x99by/8/

Comment: @Mik378 It generate an error and break the filtered list when there is more data : *Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jk37o92d/

js:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        id: 'a 1'
    }, {
        id: 'a 2'
    }, {
        id: 'b 3'
    }, {
        id: 'b 4'
    }];
    $scope.$watch('searchItems', function () {
        $scope.selected = 0;
    });
    $scope.selected = 0;

    $scope.itemFocus = function (item) {
        $scope.selected = item;
    };
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchItems" />
            <p ng-if="filteredItems[selected]">{{filteredItems[selected].id}}</p>
        </div>
        <!-- some code -->
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (list | filter:searchItems)" ng-click="itemFocus($index)">{{item.id}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds good, but if you click on 'b 4' and then update the filter by typing 'a' the highlighted item is empty :/

Comment: The $watch, that's nice, thanks I think it will do it

Comment: If you update the link in your answer, I will accept it with pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood what you want but maybe something like this will help

http://jsfiddle.net/gpvwgo97/

```
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.list = [{
            id: 'a 1'
        }, {
            id: 'a 2'
        }, {
            id: 'b 3'
        }];
        //just initiating value, could also be set by ng-init in your html
        $scope.focused = $scope.list[0];
        $scope.itemFocus = function (item) {
            $scope.focused = item;

        };
    }
```

and then

```
    <div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="searchItems" />

                <p ng-model="focused">{{focused.id}}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- some code -->
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (list | filter:searchItems)" ng-click="itemFocus(item)">{{item.id}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes this is the idea, if you are interested @sylwester gave a complete answer.